# Дается число n. Вернуть сумму от 1 до n без использования циклов

Tags: java, рекурсия, java-11

### Дается число n. Вернуть сумму от 1 до n без использования циклов. Java 11.
Задачка:
Input : a=5.
Output :a=15.
public static int sum1n(int a) return
1;
}

Как из a = 5 сделать a = ? Это должно быть рекурсией, если a-=4, то будет бесконечная функция, как этого избежать?

Comment: Подалуйста, приведите ваши попытки решения.

Comment: Рекурсия провалится  для достаточно большого `n`.  Найдите и используйте формулу суммы арифметической прогрессии.

Comment: Для сложения определенного количества целых чисел в диапазоне от 1 до заданного значения N используется формула: (N× (N+1))/2

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку от вас требуют именно рекурсию, нужно предусмотреть условие остановки. Оно будет особенно простым, если вести суммирование сверху вниз.

Псевдокод для рекурсии:

```
int sumn(int n) {
   if (n < 1) 
      return 0;
   return n + sumn(n-1);
}
```

Тело функции можно свести к одной строчке при использовании тернарного оператора

```
   return (n>0)? n+sumn(n-1): 0;
```

Comment: @Дар Ну что, разобрались?